# what the best data augmentation for the time series data

Tags: data-augmentation

I have force plate data and smartsole data. I want to make a regression model to predict force plate data using smartInsole data. I want to add variations to input and output data and find the relationship between the two using data augmentation. My smartsole have 89 sensor points. The data I have is force plate(15000,1) and SmartInsole (15000,89). What kind of data augmentation is suitable to my case. So I want that the 89 force plate data have a correlation on each force plate data.

my smartinsole data:
[image]

my force plate data:
[image]

Dataset:
if you want to help me you can use the following dataset. when you load the force plate data, just select the data in the fx column only
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YCH_IQCeHeCPdjsImtFJF8ohLmqqbTIU/view?usp=sharing